# Using New Relic with Sitecore

Tags: sitecore, newrelic

I am testing New Relic with Sitecore CMS.  All of the New Relic web transactions are being sent to the items layout file, so I am unable to drill into item level details in New Relic.

I am trying to use the New Relic API to call `SetTransactionName` and set it to the items URL, but I can't seem to make it work.  I have created an `httprequestbegin` pipeline processor, and I have put it right at the end, right after:

```
<processor type="Sitecore.Pipelines.HttpRequest.ExecuteRequest, Sitecore.Kernel"/>
```

I have the New Relic API assembly installed, and is also in my bin folder.  Here is the line of code that I am trying to run.

```
NewRelic.Api.Agent.NewRelic.SetTransactionName("Custom", Sitecore.Context.RawUrl);
```

Any ideas what I am possibly doing wrong?  All web transactions still show up as the items layout file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm setting the transaction name in the `httpRequestProcessed` pipeline and that works. Started out using the `httpRequestBegin` but I found that is was not working every time. Also remember that your request must take longer than 500 ms to execute before NewRelic picks it up.

Additional integration points I did with Sitecore:

- Log4Net Appender that reports to NewRelic using `NoticeError`
- HttpModule picking up Application_Error and reporting to NewRelic using `NoticeError`
- Use Item path to name transactions and use `AddCustomParameter` to add Language, Database, User etc.

Comment: Can you share the Log4Net Appender you've written to funnel log entries to New Relic?

Comment: @Piedone, sure thing, here you go: https://gist.github.com/pbering/dc35f94360d73252a052

Comment: @pbering would you be interested in turning this into a community module?  If you are prepared to share the code with me I will genericise it and package it for the Marketplace.

Answer (score 1):

There is a module on the marketplace that sorts all this out:

http://marketplace.sitecore.net/en/Modules/New_Relic.aspx

Comment: Note that [link-only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which  tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.

Answer (score 0):

We had similar issues when we started using New Relic with our Sitecore application about 18 or so months back. Unfortunately nobody was using New Relic with Sitecore at the time. What we settled on was to add the following code to a base Page class that every page in our site inherits:

```
    // --- Set custom transaction name for New Relic.
NewRelic.Api.Agent.NewRelic.SetTransactionName("Pages", Sitecore.Context.Item.Template.FullName));

// --- Set custom parameter to store raw url to assist with diagnostics.
NewRelic.Api.Agent.NewRelic.AddCustomParameter("RawUrl", Request.RawUrl);
```

For our application template names are enough to distinguish trends and we added the custom parameter to stuff the entire RawUrl (we noticed oddities at the time where New Relic wasn't capturing the complete url for us, that might not be the case any longer).